# DNS issue on windows

Tags: windows-7, dns

I have Windows 7. I can resolve hostname via `nslookup` correctly but other programs fail to resolve hostnames:

```
C:\>nslookup myserver.mycompany.com
Server:  mydns.mycompany.com
Address:  192.168.14.10

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    xk11.service.mycompany.com
Address:  192.168.35.50
Aliases:  myserver.mycompany.com
          myserver.service.mycompany.com


C:\>ping myserver.mycompany.com
Ping request could not find host myserver.mycompany.com. Please check the name and try again.

C:\>ping 192.168.35.50

Pinging 192.168.35.50 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.35.50: bytes=32 time=134ms TTL=51
Reply from 192.168.35.50: bytes=32 time=91ms TTL=51
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: I tried `ipconfig.exe /flushdns` but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it before, fixed an issue on your DNS server, and then tried again?  nslookup will query the DNS server every time, but ping will use a cached reply if it has one.  So if you've unsuccessfully tried pinging before, it'll remember that, until you clear the cache.  You can either run "ipconfig /flushdns", or just reboot, to clear it.

Comment: I tried I tried `ipconfig.exe /flushdns` but it does not help. I guess reboot is a solution but I believe there is something better and I want to know what really happened.

Comment: The example you used was an ALIAS; I don't suppose there's any difference if you try by A name? Also, any chance of getting a Wireshark capture to see that the packets are going out OK?